# DynamoDB scan() ResultSet has no attribute keys

Tags: amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-dynamodb, boto

I'm querying two dynamo db tables using scan to get all the items inside, storing them in a list, and then returning them ( all this within a Flask app). Pretty simple, nothing fancy.

The issue is that for one it works without an issue, but for the other I get this:

```
for entry in squads_info:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/dynamodb/layer2.py", line 125, in __iter__
response = self.response
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/dynamodb/layer2.py", line 92, in response
return self.next_response() if self._response is None else self._response
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/dynamodb/layer2.py", line 104, in next_response
self._response = self.callable(**self.kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/dynamodb/layer1.py", line 577, in scan
return self.make_request('Scan', json_input, object_hook=object_hook)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/dynamodb/layer1.py", line 127, in make_request
return json.loads(response_body, object_hook=object_hook)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 351, in loads
return cls(encoding=encoding, **kw).decode(s)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 366, in decode
obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 382, in raw_decode
obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/dynamodb/types.py", line 347, in decode
return decoder(attr[dynamodb_type])
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/dynamodb/types.py", line 377, in _decode_l
return [self.decode(i) for i in attr]
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/dynamodb/types.py", line 338, in decode
dynamodb_type = list(attr.keys())[0]
AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'keys'
```

Here is the code for the first scan:

```
def get_browsers():
    # the database table instance that can be scanned
    browsers = get_table_connection('Browser')
    # a list of the environments in the table
    browser_list = []
    # getting the full list of environments in the table
    results = browsers.scan()

   # add a dictionary entry for each result we get
   for result in results:
       entry = {
           "name": result['name'],
           "versions": result['versions']
        }

        browser_list.append(entry)

   # return the env_list 
   return jsonify(result=browser_list)
```

And here is the failing scan code.

```
@logger_app.route("/squad-information", methods=['GET'])
def get_squad_info():
   # get connection to db
   squads = get_table_connection('Squad')

   # we need to return all the information we have stored in this table, so a    scan should do
   squads_info = squads.scan()


   # start building up the response
   # response is an array of dictionaries
   response = []

   for entry in squads_info:
      response_entry = {
          "name": entry['name'],
          "squad_id": entry['squad_id'],
          "test_suites": entry['test_suites']
      }

      response.append(response_entry)

return jsonify(squads=response)
```

Both tables have at least one element within them. The difference is that the first returns a result, whereas the second doesn't. Any help would more than appreciated. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The issue was using DynamoDB version 1 (i.e. the deprecated one). Once I switched to connecting with the new version of the table and performed the scan with the appropriate method, it worked.

Hope this helps other tormented souls who get confused by cross-version mismatches.